# pixel size in FLEX Stage 3D

Tags: apache-flex, pixel, stage3d

I'm trying to do some pixel art using FLEX Stage 3D (with minko engine). I want a pixel size on the viewport of 4 "real pixels".

I think I'm not being very clear, so lets have an example. This is what I have now :
[image]

And this is what I want to have (so it looks like pixel art).
[image]
The point is that I have absolutely no idea how I should do. I've tried re-sizing the viewport down and up, unsuccessfully.

Any idea will be very welcomed.

Comment: use image button to upload image in stack overflow.

Comment: So it seems your intention is to design things not as pixel art but then have the pixel art generated for you (basically by taking a single pixel and making it into a bigger "pixel" by using a block of real pixels).  If your plan is to just run your assets through this filtering process then using the assets I could see doing this using bitmapData, you can use the draw method to pass along a DisplayObject and then iterate over the pixels and use a combo of getPixel and fillRect to replace the real pixels (this may get a bit tricky) doing this in real time I'd say maybe a shader?

Comment: I've decided to do full time game/mobile development for a bit so I've been researching a fair amount about indy game development and from what I understand pixel art is taken very seriously by some and generally the people I've seen doing it are something of perfectionists (surprisingly), so I doubt if many people are doing it this way.  Also if you're not concerned with tight control of how the pixels end up being drawn and are okay with some anti-aliasing you could just scale it twice in photoshop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to do that in real time you should write your own shader for that. As i remember minko offers quite good solution for that.. a shader language so you can write them in as3, so no AGAL. 
Other idea is to set viewport antialias to 0. If it could be done by setting antialias to -5 your problem could be solved super easy :)

Comment: Actually I did a shader for that. It works fine : http://answers.aerys.in/discussion/235/pixelization-post-processing-shader
Thanks for your answer!